# What is contex_canceled error in Geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, rinkeby

I'm trying to run a public method in my smart contract in `rinkeby` network. But it fails with following error in Geth,

```
INFO [02-06|06:01:19.593] Served eth_call   conn=172.17.42.1:23241 reqid=1 t=320.98µs    err="context canceled"
```

What is the reason for this error. Please note that I'm running my Geth node inside a Docker container.